# SQL to flag errors and get latest valid status

Tags: sql, db2, zos, analytical

Please help with the below scenario, I have set of records that I need to loop over for a given ID and Case_Type and mark the record as Valid or ERROR.

Since it is an Audit table, the events has to be in order, like **open/pend/done** or **open/done**

So Rec_no 1 and 4 are ERRORs in the sample data below. Rec_no 5 (for ID 9) carries the Latest Valid status (which is 'done').

Below is the sample records 
:

```html
Rec_num  ID  Case_Type  Status
1      9      1      Pend     -- ERROR (Out of Order)
2        9       1       open
3        8       1       open
4        9       1       open       -- ERROR (Duplicate)
5        9       1       done       
6        9       1       open
7        8       1       done
```

I need the following output :

```js
Lag and Lead functions are not available in DB2 z/OS.

This is what i have till now. I guess I need something like 

max(case when previous_stat = 'open' and (Status = 'Pend' or Status = 'done' then 1 else 0) as Flag over(partition by ID,Case_Type order by Rec_num).


WITH     TST AS                                                                                                                                         
(SELECT 1 AS Rec_Num, 9 AS ID, 1 AS Case_Type, 'Pend'  AS Status FROM               
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 AS Rec_Num, 9 AS ID, 1 AS Case_Type, 'open'  AS Status FROM               
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL                                                     
SELECT 3 AS Rec_Num , 8 AS ID,2  AS Case_Type, 'open'  AS Status FROM                
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1  UNION ALL                                                    
SELECT 4 AS Rec_Num, 9 AS ID, 1 AS Case_Type, 'open' AS Status FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL                                                                      
SELECT 5 AS Rec_Num, 9 AS ID, 1 AS Case_Type, 'done' AS Status FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL                                                                      
SELECT 6 AS Rec_Num, 9 AS ID, 1 AS Case_Type, 'open'  AS Status FROM                 
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
union all
SELECT 7 AS Rec_Num, 8 AS ID, 1 AS Case_Type,  'done' AS Status FROM                 
SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)                                                              
                                                                               
SELECT ID,Case_Type, Status, MAX(Status) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,Case_Type ORDER BY    
Rec_Num ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS PREVIOUS_STAT      from TST
```

```html
Rec_num  ID  Case_Type  Status    Flag
1      9      1      Pend      ERROR
2        9       1       open      Valid
3        8       1       open      Valid
4        9       1       open      ERROR
5        9       1       done      Valid 
6        9       1       open      ERROR
7        8       1       done      Valid
```

Comment: What's creating the values in `Rec_Num`?  I dislike using auto-generated ids for ordering purposes (they're effectively memory addresses, and essentially random).  Do you have an actual date/timestamp column?  What is the ordering _supposed_ to be (where does `pend` go)?

Comment: ...How are you supposed to know that the `Pend` isn't valid, as opposed to the `Open` (that it's out of order, or missing)?  Detecting duplicates isn't bad, but detecting out-of-order stuff can be troublesome. It'd be easier to detect that something's wrong with the entire set.

Comment: Thanks @Clockwork-Muse for reading and trying to asnwer my question. Sorry, this is the first time that I am using this beautiful forum !!

Comment: The business rules are  in this order  Open --> Pend --> Done. Anything coming "out of order", should be marked as ERROR. The Rec_Num is actually the    Transaction Number and I have to use this for ordering, since this is an Audit trail, I am not supposed to modify the order of records. Please let me know and thanks for the input.

Comment: This isn't really a forum, but whatever.  Your question is reasonably clear, etc.  What should happen in the case of `id = 8`, which doesnt have a `pend` record?  Is it optional?  In the case of records being out of order, you have to consider them both invalid, unless there's some other info you're not telling us - there's no way to know which one was placed incorrectly.